# How to read row value of particular column from a text file and assign the value to xml element using SAX parser and java

Tags: java, xml, sax

I have text file as follows.
Each column is separated by a tab

```
Material    Sales Org   Dist. Chanl Description 1   Description 2   Prdt. Hirachy.  UoM Gross Weight    
CERTIFICATE 2.1 2092    11  CERTIFICATE 2.1     220242200020002000  EA  0.000   0.000   KG          
CERTIFICATE 2.2 2092    11  CERTIFICATE 2.2     220242200020002000  EA  0.002   0.002   KG  0.070   
PACKAGING_ECC   2092    11  PACKAGING_ECC       220242200020002000  EA  0.000   0.000   KG          
TRAVEL_TIME_ECC 2092    11  TRAVEL_TIME_ECC     220243200020002000  EA  0.000   0.000   KG
```

I have to read this file and convert this text file to xml.

I have used Java sax parser to generate XML.

my sample xml is look like as follows

```
<each_record>
        <category>test category</category>
        <action>add</action>
        <table_name><![CDATA[abc_2092]]></table_name>
        <PartNumber><![CDATA[CERTIFICATE 2.1]]></PartNumber>
       <DistrChannel><![CDATA[11]]></DistrChannel>

    </each_record>
```

But I have stuck to read specific row value of particular column from the above text file and assign to the xml element.

For Example: in the above example, partNumber element has a value of CERTIFICATE 2.1 which is under column "Material" and For DistributionChannel element value is 11 which comes under third column.

I need to generate the set of elements for a number of rows in the text file. so could some one suggest me the best way to achieve it?

I have one concern, is SAX parser better than JAXB? My input text file contains 69 columns and around 6000 rows hence I have choosed SAX because its performance is better. 
is it good idea to create a POJO class with all the column values as attributes,  read the file and assign the values to java objects and then generate the xml from java objects using JAXB? Please suggest

Comment: Have you tried this: http://andrewjwelch.com/code/xslt/csv/csv-to-xml_v2.html

Comment: I have text file and not csv file and each column are separated by tab. I need to generate the xml elements equals to the number of rows in a file.

Comment: why do you assume sax's performance is better? It is a lot difficult to use... and your code is likely to be verbose, ugly and hard to maintain...